# Ошибка запуска MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows

Подскажите пожалуйста какой файл он не может найти?

[image]

Что вообще делать в таких случаях?

Вот содержание конфигурации:

```
[client]
port=3306
host=127.0.0.1
[mysqld]
port=3306
bind-address=127.0.0.1
enable-named-pipe
basedir="i:/Server/mysql/"
datadir="i:/Server/mysql/data/"

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Answer (score 1):

Система не может найти сам исполняемый файл сервиса.

Выполните

```
sc qc mysql
```

вывод бует вида

```
SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin\mysqld
-max-nt" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\my.ini" "MySQL
"
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : MySQL
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```

Начало BINARY_PATH_NAME - путь к mysqld-max-nt или чему-то похожему - это и есть путь к сервису. Проверьте что этот файл существует.

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены что существуют такие папки?

```
basedir="i:/Server/mysql/"
datadir="i:/Server/mysql/data/"
```

Если да, посмотрите в логи.